# Flickity-fade slider not working after following the installation docs from github; flickity just run like the regular slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, flickity

I'm following this flickity slide fade docs
[FlickityFade Installation](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity-fade)

> Here is the css cdn package

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity-fade@2/flickity-fade.css">
```

> Here is the carousel html and the script set up

```
<div class="testimonial-carousel">
     ....carousels div....
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-fade@2/flickity-fade.js"></script>
<script>
    $('.testimonial-carousel').flickity({
        // options
        fade: true,
        cellAlign: 'left',
        contain: true,
        prevNextButtons: false
    });
</script>
```

i don't figure out why this slide fade not working, only run in the dom like i am using normal flickity package
but, it shown error like link below

[Error screenshot from my console log](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/70867121/165246199-7781dffa-3682-4dde-8dae-059df38b4ab1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution here [Flickity issues](https://github.com/metafizzy/flickity-fade/issues/17#issuecomment-1099286185)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just Use fade v1 with filckity v2 :

here is the CSS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.min.css"
    />
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/flickity-fade@1/flickity-fade.css">
```

here is the Js :

```
 <!-- Flickity js  JavaScript v2-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity@2/dist/flickity.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<!-- fade JS  v1-->
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flickity-fade@1/flickity-fade.js"></script>
```